# How to access a specific property from HttpErrorResponse using interceptor

Tags: typescript, .net-6.0, interceptor, fluentvalidation, angular14

I'm struggling to access the requestDate value to display the error message, I tried different ways but nothing works. The error occurs in one of classes using fluentvalidation library. In the example here, the HttpErrorResponse  contains only the requestDate error but in other scenario's there may be more errors on different properties.

[image]

```
   @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private notification: AppNotificationsService
  ) {}
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((httpErrorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (httpErrorResponse.error) {
            **let errorMsg = httpErrorResponse.error.errors.requestDate[0];**
            this.notification.show(
                this.translate.instant('Error.Title'),
                errorMsg,
                styleEnum.error
            );
        }    
        return throwError(() => new Error(errorMsg));
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The property is with capital "R": `RequestDate`.